# Use request/reply without changing the design of the response

Tags: .net, rabbitmq, masstransit

The Service

```
   Public Class GetContactConsumer        
        Implements Consumes(Of Schema.KlantService.IGetContactV1).Context

        Public Sub Consume(message As IConsumeContext(Of Schema.KlantService.IGetContactRequestV1)) Implements MassTransit.Consumes(Of IConsumeContext(Of Schema.KlantService.IGetContactRequestV1)).All.Consume
            HandleMessageAsync(message)
        End Sub
        Private Async Sub HandleMessageAsync(context As IConsumeContext(Of Schema.KlantService.IGetContactPersonenRequestV1))
            Dim Id = context.Message.Id
            Dim contacten = Await New ContactPersonenController().GetContactPersonen(Id)
            Dim response As New GetContactResponseV1
            response.Contacten = contacten
            context.Respond(response)
        End Sub
    End Class
```

MassTransit supports request reply mechanisms, but what bothers me is that the design of the responder depends on it.
I have setup this service to support RR, however if I would like to send something from another service (using the normal event based practice). Using this setup in combination with a consumer for the response, the response will end up in the error queue.

My guess is that this is because the lack of ACK that was sent from my consumer.
Is there any way that I can use request reply in eg an MVC application, but use regular events for service-to-service communication?

Comment: I have a solution using the TPL. If anyone really wants to see it, I'll explain it in an answer.

Comment: the question has 8 votes so it would be great if you could answer it